# Jquery + условие

Tags: jquery

Мне нужно составить условие так:
перезагружаем страницу,
Eсли страница перезагружена, то выводим текст.
Как я делаю:

```
location.reload();
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#result").append(html);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Задачку можно решить, например, так: непосредственно перед перезагрузкой страницы поставить короткоживущую куку, а в $(document).ready проверять её наличие и по результатам выводить/не выводить текст.